# Gitolite many users having specific working directory and all are using one repository

Tags: hook, gitolite

I'm using [Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/master-toc.html).
This is my folder Structure:

```
/var/www/demo.com/user1   
/var/www/demo.com/user2  
/var/www/demo.com/user3
```

I have created one repository named `demo.git`.
I have created three gitolite users  `user1`, `user2` and `user3`.

Now, my question is that when `user1` clone or commit or push or pull changes, then **it only should change `user1`'s working directory**, and same as `user2` and `user3`.
How would you enforce that with Gitolite?

Answer (score 0):

When `user1` pull, it will always changes only his/her own working directory.

But when `user1` pushes, he/she pushes to *one* gitolite-manage repo.
If you need to offer personal branch per user, you can look at the **[gitolite personal branches](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/special.html#pers)**, in order to enforce `user1` to push *only* in a specific branch.

> A user "`alice`" (if she's in the userlist) can then push any branches inside `personal/alice/`.
>   Which means she can push `personal/alice/foo` and `personal/alice/bar`, but NOT `personal/alice`.
>
> (Background: at runtime the "`USER`" component will be replaced by the name of the invoking user. Access is determined by the right hand side, as usual).
>
> Compared to using arbitrary branch names on the same server, this:
>
> - Reduces namespace pollution by corralling all these ad hoc branches into the "personal/" namespace.
> - Reduces branch name collision by giving each developer her own sub-hierarchy within that.
> - Removes the need to think about access control, because a user can push only to his own sub-hierarchy.